# ngx-monaco-editor + Karma test runner - how to get monaco instance loaded into test suite?

Tags: angular, karma-runner, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I am making use of @materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor in my application and am having trouble getting the `monaco` globally installed lib to be recognized during unit test runs with Karma+Jasmine.

Component

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MonacoEditorLoaderService } from '@materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor';
import { filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-editor',
    templateUrl: './my-editor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-editor.component.scss']
})

export class MyEditorComponent implements OnInit {

    public modelUri: monaco.Uri;

    constructor(private monacoLoaderService: MonacoEditorLoaderService) {
        this.monacoLoaderService.isMonacoLoaded$.pipe(
            filter(isLoaded => isLoaded === true),
            take(1),
        ).subscribe(() => {
            this.monacoLoaderService.isMonacoLoaded$
                .pipe(
                    filter(isLoaded => isLoaded),
                    take(1)
                )
                .subscribe(() => {
                    // This seems to be the issue during test runs - monaco is not defined
                    monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({});
                })
            })
    }
}
```

In my component file, `monaco` is being resolved from interfaces exposed in the `@materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor`:

[image]

Test Spec

```
describe('MyEditorComponent Test Suite:', () => {
    let component: MyEditorComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyEditorComponent>;
    let tagsService: TagsService;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyEditorComponent],
            providers: [ MonacoEditorLoaderService ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyEditorComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('Should create component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

When it comes to unit testing my component, I get errors from Karma to tell me that monaco is not defined:
[image]

I am struggling with getting Monaco to be correctly picked up by Karma, at least I believe that's my problem here.

When installing `@materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor` the `monaco-editor` package is also installed, and so I have also tried adding the monaco-editor script into the scripts property of my test project config section in my angular.json file:

```
"test": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
    "options": {
      "main": "src/test.ts",
      "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "src/styles",
          "node_modules"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": [
        "node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.main.js"
      ],
      ...
    }
}
```

This makes no difference, so what's the right approach here to get `monaco` registered and picked up in my test suite correctly?

**UPDATE**

Based on @Lucho's suggestion, I have replicated my issue in the following Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/materia-ngx-monaco-editor-ng9-zdpc2h?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Note, that unlike in Lucho's approach, I am not providing the MONACO_PATH to a CDN path, and instead I am adding an entry in the `assets` property of my application and test project config section of the angular.json to ensure the monaco-editor library is made available

```json
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/monaco-editor",
    "output": "assets/monaco-editor/"
}
```

So, although I am attempting to provide this in the test section of the angular.json file, it seems perhaps its not being used somehow in the actual test run?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get one example working for you however it's ugly IMO but it gets the job done.

The ugly part is that i couldn't find a way to import monaco globally in stackblitz however i got it working through the CDN:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: MONACO_PATH,
      useValue: "https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.19.3/min/vs"
    }
  ]
```

**Note:** If you using Angular 8 below you have to take in consideration is that i found this [ticket](https://github.com/materiahq/ngx-monaco-editor/issues/19) which forces you the version below 0.18.1.

Lastly the actual tests since I got it working through the CDN, unfortunately you have to consider the timing of getting resources so then you have to introduce some timeouts and let jasmine know when things have finished:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [],
      declarations: []
    }).compileComponents();

    setTimeout(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
  }));

  it("Should create component", async(done: DoneFn) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });

  it("Check if code in editor is populated", async(done: DoneFn) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let code = component.monacoComponent.editor.getValue();
      expect(code).toEqual(expectedCode);
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-unit-test-monaco-editor?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts) with the tests, ENJOY!

Comment: Thanks @Lucho, i would rather not have to add explicit timeouts to the tests as this lead to test flakiness ultimately. I'm going to update my question with a further stackblitz that will showcase my setup better and hopefully help in diagnosing the problem

Comment: I assume you have tried with `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';` in your component, meaning you have to take a non global approach?

Comment: Hey, nice ides! I just tried it, but stackblitz complains that it cannot find the `monaco-editor` package even though i see its installed as a dependency. I tried uninstalling and re-installing but it made no difference - frustrating!

Comment: Don't do it in stackblitz, do it locally where you running your tests.

Comment: Hmm, when I try, I get errors from the compiler due to duplicate definitions found between `node_modules/@materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor/lib/interfaces/monaco.d.ts` and `node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts`. The typings that come from `@materia-ui` already include exporting a `monaco` namespace.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json file add `"exclude": [ "node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts" ]` with the assumption `editor.api.d.ts` is extended in the `monaco.d.ts`

Comment: or even better in the `asset` property where you updated your post add `"ignore": [  "node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts" ]`

Comment: Still not working, I have given up and now stubbed the monaco object and necessary props my component needs to access on the `global` thats exposed in the test suite. That's working well enough fr me, and means I can easily setup spies if I need any

Comment: @mindparse Can you please explain how you did the fix? I am also stuck with the same issue at this moment and no luck finding any fix.